Тестовые заглушки для React Native приложений
Кто силен в этом? Поделитесь простым быстрым способом решить такую задачу
Вводные
Есть приложение на React Native. Оно имеет несколько экранов и логично, что самый первый экран это вход в систему.
Что необходимо
Надо поставить какую нибудь заглушку, чтобы при разработке этот экран появляся, но принимал любые значения (или определенные) и пропускал дальше, без необходимости поднимать тестовый бэк
Что сейчас
На данном этапе реализовано так, что хук постоянно принимает значение true и пропускает дальше, но здесь есть вероятность того, что данная конструкция улетит в git и откроет доступ всем кому надо и не надо.
function SignInScreen({navigation, isFailLogin}) {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Main',
      headerShown: false,
    });
  });
  const [isLogin, setLogin] = useState(true); // вот здесь
return....

Вопрос
Есть ли готовое решение для таких случаев? чтобы не изобретать

Ну а что если вмето true поставить такую конструкцию или похожую process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

У Экспо есть небольшая "приставка" к переменным окружения https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/

@ksa старые проект, не отягащенный expo окружением и фичами

@SwaD хотел сократить вопрос и не все понято верно. Это просто как пример того, что надо реализовать. Если брать все приложение целиком, то естественно имеются разные виды доступа (которые также глушатся/определяются вручную), рутина с обновлением/добавлением токена (которые как значение определено вручную). Но в общем, я думаю, что можно так решить, просто все это определить через переменные окружения
